# Fastest way to pass json from node server to client at page load

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have a big JS object in my node server
I want to pass it to the client **at the moment when he asks for the index.html page**. He will use it for Backbone model creation.

I already have the JSON when I send him index.html so no need for AJAX/socket.io
For the moment, I did it this way :

```
Node - controller.js

res.render('index', {myObject: myObject});


Client - index.ejs

<script type="text/javascript">
        var myObject= <%- JSON.stringify(myObject) %>;
</script>
```

This works but I was wondering if there is a better way, or at least a faster one (better perfs) ?

Comment: Just to clarify again... one BIG JSON Obj or many large ones? As vololaz said, GET is the best for a file, while IOSocket can be used to keep the connection open if your sending lots of data in intervals ie live data from your controller.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but your `<script>` example is unsafe and can expose XSS because you are using `<%-`. e.g. `JSON.stringify({key: "</script><script>alert('hi');</script><script>" })`. JSON is also not always valid JS. http://timelessrepo.com/json-isnt-a-javascript-subset

Comment: @DeanMeehan I am sending this data just once, with the html page. No need for ajax or socket IO, I already have the json when the client asks for the page so I am only looking for the best way to serve the json in the Index.html directly

Comment: @loganfsmyth the index.ejs template is rendered by the server so the client receives the script with the javascript in simpe text format, as if it was wrote in the file. I am not doing any AJAX, there is no JSONP or anything here

Answer (score 0):

probably load this object by AJAX GET 
the data can be rendered by http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.jsonp

Comment: Yes but this means sending the page to the client, then making him do an ajax request to my server, and responding with the JSON, while I can just send the JSON at the moment when the client asks me for the page

Answer (score 0):

In controller.js you can do:

```
res.json({foo: 'bar'});
```

You can assign the result to a Javascript variable directly as it is guaranteed to be JSON.

Comment: Yes but this way I respond to the client with JSON, while what I want is respond to the client with my index.ejs (compiled to html), including a script tag with my JSON in a variable so that the client can use it for backbone